# How to split DateTime field and bind to GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, gridview

I have a DateTime Field `BirthDate` in my Table. I want to split it into `Day`,`month`,`Year` and bind it to my `GridView`.

This is the design of my GridView:

```
 <asp:datagrid id="grdTransactions" runat="server" Width="1000px" PageSize="25" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="datagrid">
 <SelectedItemStyle CssClass="datagridselecteditemcell"></SelectedItemStyle>
 <AlternatingItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="datagridalternatingitemcell"></AlternatingItemStyle>
  <ItemStyle Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="datagriditemcell"></ItemStyle>
   <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="datagridheadercell"></HeaderStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="BirthDate" HeaderText="Date">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundColumn>

         <%--Add Day,Month,Year Columns here --%>

    </Columns>
 </asp:datagrid>
```

This is how I am simply binding my DataSet result to the GridView:

```
dsCards = Utilities.GetCardGCDBReport(txtFname.text,txtLName.Text)
sRecCount = dsCards.Tables(0).Rows.Count
grdTransactions.DataSource = dsCards
grdTransactions.DataBind()
```

Is it possible to break the `Birthdate` (which is a DateTime Field) and then `Bind` those values to columns of GridView?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I achieved the results by using the `DataFormatString` property of the `GridView`.
This is how I tried to split my `DateTime` Field

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="BirthDate" HeaderText="Day" DataFormatString="{0:dd}"> 
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle> 
</asp:BoundColumn> 
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="BirthDate" HeaderText="Month" DataFormatString="{0:MMM}"> 
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle> 
</asp:BoundColumn> 
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="BirthDate" HeaderText="Year" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy}"> 
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
 </asp:BoundColumn>
```